# How to convert content of file in list by characters?

Tags: python, string, char

I have a string in the file, for example, 'HELLO', and I need to convert the string in list by characters, 'H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O'. How to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your file is called `myfile.txt`:

```
In [1]: with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as myfile:
   ...:     mystring = myfile.read()
   ...:     print(list(mystring))
   ...:     
['H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O']
```